# Verbal compounds such as come-to-be, come-to-know, come-to-X

Tags: expressions, verbs, semantics, dashes

Reading about intellectual history and the history of natural science, I have very often come across the expression `to come-to-be` as a synonym for `to come into being`, `to start to exist`, `to originate`, and so on.

I also see commonly used such verbal expressions as `to come to know` (for `to learn`, `to acquire knowledge of`) or `to come to see` (for `to realize`), and so on.

My question now is twofold:

1. If one is allowed to write `to come-to-be` and `to come-to-know` and `to come-to-see`, is there some definite end to this or am I allowed also to write `to come-to-converge`, `to come-to-acquire`, `to come-to-X`?
2. If I am allowed also to use other combinations, then what about the dashes/hyphens in these expressions. I usually see `come-to-be` with dashes, but the `to come to know` without (I think). Why is that so? Should one be consistent? Or has `to come-to-be` become a lexical entity that warrants a particular use of dashes, whereas the other expressions are simply compound verbs that do not warrant an equal use of dashes? What about "to-come-to-converge` and other less usual instances of such combinations?

Comment: Do you *really* mean you frequently see these terms with ***hyphens**?* I don't recognise the usage at all.

Comment: Because you highlight *hyphens*, I am not sure whether you just want to alert me that I misused a technical term or whether your question is an honest one. If the latter, then, yes. There is a work by Aristotle that is usually (and virtually exclusively) referred to as "On Coming-to-be and Passing-away". In discussions about this text, I often see that things "come-to-be" and even that they "pass-away". Due to that fact, I myself always wrote "to come-to-be", so that I now asked my question about the limits and justification of such a habit.

Comment: I'd say that [your Aristotle context](https://www.google.com/search?q=Aristotle+%22either+coming+to+be%22+%22passing+away%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) is highly specialised. That link shows 81 (mostly hyphenated) instances citing what I assume is a specific translation. A much smaller proportion of these 1150 [more general references to the text](https://www.google.com/search?q=Aristotle+%22coming+to+be%22+%22passing+away%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) include those hyphens, even though they all denote exactly the same (highly specialised) thing.

Comment: Alright, thank you. I take it that this, now, gives me an answer. I can (or even: should) keep `come-to-be` with hyphens *and* employ other compound verbs without hyphens.

Comment: Well, I'm no expert, but I've just had a cursory glance at what I assume is the original translation. My guess is if Aristotle were *writing in English*(or even *being translated for the first time*) those two "neologistic-multi-word" terms wouldn't be used anyway, since conceptually they're much the same as what we now refer to as the [creation/anihilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_particle) of virtual particles in quantum field theory.

Comment: ... But putting that aside, I think if you create/use a "new" neologism in that way, you probably *have* to "set it off" using quote marks, hyphens, and/or a different typeface, otherwise no-one will understand what you're doing. Since the Aristotlean context is apparently so familiar to those who study such things, *later* references can dispense with this (it does become tiresome). You probably can't, because initially *no-one* will be familiar with your coinage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Come"  + to-infinitive or "come" + "to be { participle}" are lexical expressions or approximations of *inchoative* and *perfective* verbal aspect.

Verbs in English are not inflected for aspect, so these meanings have to be made by phrases.

The dashes are unnecessary and irrelevant.

How did he come to run (or 'to be running') down the street?
--What set him in motion?

How did it come to be placed on the mantel?
-- What led to its being placed on the mantel?

Comment: But isn't the *come* in those expressions part of the idiom *"How did X come to"* and not *"come to be running"*?

Comment: @Peter Shor:  I don't understand what you're asking there.

Comment: I'm saying that you wouldn't say *"it came to be placed upon the mantel"*, in the same way you would say *"she came to believe that"*, *"he came to be aware that"*, *"she came to realize that"*, *"he came to think that"*. But maybe I'm wrong about this.

Comment: @Peter: You'd certainly say it in contexts like *What I want to know is how it came to be placed upon the mantel*. But probably not in contexts like *It came to be placed there because the butler likes to keep things tidy*.